# jqGrid toolbar search working only for the first 20 rows. The paging is 20,40,60

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jqgrid

jqGrid search is able to filter through the first 20 rows only. The grid I’m searching had 600+ rows but.

$(obj).find("#"+rowid).hide();

obj is having only first 20 rows (1 of 30 ) pages. but I need to filter through 600 rows.

Comment: Please specify if your data is local or server side. If it is local the search is through all the local data. If the data is server it depends what you return when the search is activated to the server

Comment: Please show your grid configuration

Answer (score 0):

We might just guess the way you get your data for the table, but the right way to hide some rows is to `filter your data`, not its visual representation i.e. some rows. At the point of executing of your `hide` usually only the visible page of rows exists. If I'm not wrong visiting next page will created other page of rows and so on.  That's why you are not able to hide them, because the do not exist at the DOM yet.
I'm not sure what kind of search you are doing i.e toolbar or other but you might catch the complete event and you may use following functions to get the data from the table.

```
1. jQuery ("grid_id").GetGridParam('userData')  
2. jQuery ("grid_id").GetUserData()  
3. jQuery ("grid_id").GetUserDataItem(key)
```

Then you may remove some entries you don like to show using the proper methods provided in jqGrid.

That's all I can say based on the simple way you have represented your question.